# How does one change the color of a Core Plot scatter plot?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I made a scatter plot and am trying to change the color of plotted points. Here is the analog of what I am trying to do with CPT

```
// Add line style
CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor greenColor];
dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
```

How do I do this with a CPTX scatter plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `plotSymbol` property to draw a symbol at each data point. There is a demo in the Mac version of CPTTestApp that shows all of the predefined shapes. You can create custom symbol shapes if needed.

Implement one of the following datasource methods if you need to draw different symbols for some of the data points:

```
-(NSArray *)symbolsForScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot
                 recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;
-(CPTPlotSymbol *)symbolForScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot
                           recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

Answer (score 1):

`CPTScatterPlot` has an array of symbols. It looks like these symbols are expected to by of type `CPTPlotSymbol`, and that class in turn has the usual properties that you can customize such as `lineStyle`.